# Filter items that only occurs once in a very large list

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, list, filter

I have a large list(over 1,000,000 items), which contains english words:

```
tokens = ["today", "good", "computer", "people", "good", ... ]
```

I'd like to get all the items that occurs only once in the list

now I'm using:

```
tokens_once = set(word for word in set(tokens) if tokens.count(word) == 1)
```

but it's really slow. how could I make this faster?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You iterate over a list and then for each element you do it again, which makes it O(N²). If you replace your `count` by a `Counter`, you iterate once over the list and then once again over the list of unique elements, which makes it, in the worst case, O(2N), i.e. O(N).

```
from collections import Counter

tokens = ["today", "good", "computer", "people", "good"]
single_tokens = [k for k, v in Counter(tokens).iteritems() if v == 1 ]
# single_tokens == ['today', 'computer', 'people']
```

Comment: in Python 3, `iteritems` has been renamed to `items`